# python changing a list into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

so i'm taking a python class right now and am struggling with dictionaries at the moment. my assignment is simple, i have to create a fucntion "letter_positions" which will return a dictionary of all positions of a letter in a string.

for example

```
positions = letter_positions("fifteen e's, seven f's, four g's, six h's, eight i's, four n's, five o's, six r's, eighteen s's, eight t's, four u's, three v's, two w's, three x's")

positions['e']
```

should return

```
{4, 5, 8, 14, 16, 43, 67, 83, 88, 89, 97, 121, 122, 141, 142}
```

so i'm pretty much done with the assignment but i'm running into the issue that i have all values (positions) assigned to the keys (letters) as a list.

here's my code:

```
def letter_positions(n):
    answer = {}
    n = n.lower()
    x = 0
    for letter in n:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter not in answer:
                answer[letter] = []
            answer[letter].append(x)
        x += 1
    return answer
```

so instead of getting a dictionary of positions i'm getting a list of positions.

```
positions = letter_positions("fifteen e's, seven f's, four g's, six h's, eight i's, four n's, five o's, six r's, eighteen s's, eight t's, four u's, three v's, two w's, three x's")

positions['e']
```

returns

```
[4, 5, 8, 14, 16, 43, 67, 83, 88, 89, 97, 121, 122, 141, 142]
```

is there any way for me to simply change the list into a dictionary or am i approaching this in a completely wrong way?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. `positions` is already a dictionary and the list in your answer is the value associated with the key `e`.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
def letter_positions(n):
    answer = {}
    n = n.lower()
    x = 0
    for letter in n:
        if letter.isalpha():
            answer[letter] = answer.get(letter,[])#if there is not the key letter add it as key with value an empty list
            answer[letter].append(x)
        x=x+1
    return answer
positions = letter_positions("fifteen e's, seven f's, four g's, six h's, eight i's, four n's, five o's, six r's, eighteen s's, eight t's, four u's, three v's, two w's, three x's")
print(positions['e'])
```